# Combine multer and tinypng API in node

Tags: node.js, image-uploading, image-compression, multer

does anyone know how to use [tinyPNG's API](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/nodejs#compressing-images) with multer? The docs seem deceptively simple:

```
var source = tinify.fromFile("unoptimized.jpg");
source.toFile("optimized.jpg");
```

though there's no clear indication of where this is meant to go, especially in something as convoluted as this:

```
var storage =  multer.diskStorage(
    {
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
      },

      filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        //use date to guarantee name uniqueness
        callback(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now());
      }
    }
);

//.any() allows multiple file uploads
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).any()

app.post('/api/photo', function(req,res){

    upload(req,res,function(err) {

        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }

        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});
```

Where am I meant to "intercept" the file uploaded by multer so that I can compress it with tinyPNG?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following basic sample that changes uploaded photo/gallery files:

```js
// Import express and multer.
var express = require('express');
var multer  = require('multer');

// Setup upload.
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });
var multipleFiles = upload.fields([{ name: 'photo', maxCount: 1 }, 
                                   { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }]);

// Setup tinify.
var tinify = require("tinify");
tinify.key = "YOUR_API_KEY";

// Get request handler for '/' path.
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
    res.end(
        "<form action='/api/photo' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" +
            "<input type='file' name='photo' />" +
            "<input type='file' name='gallery' multiple/>" +
            "<input type='submit' />" +
        "</form>"
    );
});

// Upload file handler with '/api/photo' path.
app.post('/api/photo', multipleFiles, function (req, res) {
    req.files['gallery'].forEach(function(file) {
       // Your logic with tinify here.
       var source = tinify.fromFile(file.path);
       source.toFile(file.path + "_optimized.jpg");
    });

    res.end("UPLOAD COMPLETED!");
});
```

Feel free to change `express` middleware how you need it, just make sure you use `upload.fields` and authenticate using `tinify.key = "YOUR_API_KEY";`

- https://github.com/expressjs/multer
- https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/nodejs#compressing-images

Comment: hey, thanks, but I need to allow the users to upload multiple files simultaneously. so the `single('photo')` limitation is no good :/

Comment: sorry, been sick. going to try later today

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked out a similar problem for myself using the tinify package and found the docs to be somewhat lacking.

I have a Vue front end collecting file uploads from the user using vue2dropzone. These are sent to a node / Express back end.
I have a need to compress the file and upload it to an S3 instance without storing on disk. That means using multer memory storage.
As a result there won’t be an ability to use tinify.fromFile() as there is no file stored locally.

In my images middleware:

```
Const multer = require(“multer”);
const tinify = require("tinify");

tinify.key = "your_key";

exports.singleFile = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).fields([{ name: "file", maxCount: 1 }]);

exports.uploadCompImage = async (req, res, next) => {
   try {
      const fileName = `${req.params.name}${path.extname(req.files.file[0].originalname)}`;
      const source = tinify.fromBuffer(req.files.file[0].buffer);
      source.store({
         service: "s3",
         aws_access_key_id: "your_id",
         aws_secret_access_key: "your_key
         region: "your_region",
         headers: {
            "Cache-Control": "public"
         },
         path: `your_bucket/your_folder/${fileName}`
      });
      return res.status(200).send(`path_to_file/${fileName}`)
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
   }
}
```

Then in my routes file:

```
Const images = require(“../middleware/images”);

// skipped several lines for brevity

productRouter
      .route("/images/:name")
      .post(images.singleFile, images.uploadCompImage)
```

This process creates a multer singleFile upload to memoryStorage, making the file available at req.files.file[0] (req.files[“file”] because I specified “file” as the name in multer fields, loop through this array if uploading multiple).
After setting that up I get the file name, set the source by using tinify to read from req.files.file[0].buffer as a buffer.
Then I set the source to my s3 instance and send back a public link to the file.

Hopefully this answer helps you. I could definitely see altering the process to change where the file goes or even write it to disk by altering the multer options.