# How to fetch image file on node.js server and not store it in disk but only store it in memory and send it to tinypng

Tags: node.js, image, google-cloud-storage, multer

I want to send an image to node.js server from where first i will compress it using **tinypng** api and then i need to store final compressed image to my google cloud storage. Now i searched some modules for fetching images on the server end, i read this anser about **multer** [Combine multer and tinypng API in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633991/combine-multer-and-tinypng-api-in-node) but what it does is it ask for storage destination where it will store the image on the disk but for my use case i do not want to store image on my server directory instead of i just want to store it in memory so that once i get it i will send it to tinypng from where i will further send it to my google cloud storage buckets. Now if anyone of you can tell me **how to fetch the image on server without storing it on my server disk** then it will become very easy for me to further send that image file to tinypng and from there to google cloud storage buckets.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use multer,
this is normal configuration -

var multer  = require('multer');
   var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

do not use **options object** property and it will treat it as in memory.

i.e. var upload = multer();